# Android navigation layout items align to left and right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create toolbar menu in android fragment.
Menu layout code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
        android:title="back"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And this is how it renders:
[toolbar menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIa1Z.png)

This isn't how I want it. Instead I want back arrow at left of toolbar and other to at right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate space for back space and others icons like that and you you can use by adding attribute

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back"
```

Or set it programitically

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
```

and the icon for the right,  you have done it right just delete the back icon because it doesn't where it belongs

and call the callback for navigationback as

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```